# Host a c# worker in Azure

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, azure, web

I have a worker coded using C# and I'd like to host it in Azure.

So I create an Azure automation account and I tried to import my worker project as a new runbook but I find that the runbook must be  [built on PowerShell Workflow](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-automation-runbook-management/) !!!

So I need to know

1. If there is a way to import my C# worker?
2. If not, I'd like to know How can I host my worker using my Azure account ?

**NB:** The worker is for sitemap generation

Thanks,

Comment: Is there a specific framework that the worker is written for? IE: Is it a console app, a windows service, etc?

Comment: @CtrlDot : no it is a library class which uses Entity framework to generate xml files ( sitemaps ) . the errors were logged in text files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could consider using [Azure WebJobs](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingWindowsAzureWebJobs.aspx) or [Azure Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/).

[This](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-compare-logic-apps-ms-flow-webjobs) article helps you in deciding which one to use.

If you need more control over the VM (like installing custom software) you could consider hosting your code as a '[Cloud service](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-choose-me)'

I would start of with Azure Functions to get something up and running quickly and then build on top of it.